# Combining not, and, and size

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

MongoDB has a wonderful problem described by https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-478 (and a more generic version at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-589)

As a workaround, I'm trying to express my query as a composition of and, not and size:

```
     { '$match' => {
      '$and' => [
        items: {'$and' => ['$size' => 0, '$size' => 1, ... until the length I need is reached]},
        ...
      ],
    }},
```

I keep getting `failed with error 10068: "exception: invalid operator: $and"`. Am I overlooking something really obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you are trying to use `$and`, chances are you might not get any results because the query will try to find documents with items whose size should match ALL the sizes you give (0,1,...length you need). I suppose you should try `$or` instead. Second, below is what you might really need:

```
db.test.aggregate(
  {$match:{
    $or:[ {items:{$size:0}}, {items:{$size:4}} ]} // just include all your size conditions
  }
)
```

Comment: Oh, so I need to repeat items inside and/or and not the other way around?

Comment: Yes I think so. That is the reason you get the `invalid operator` error.